# Making Admob App on iOS, Getting Thread 1 Error

Tags: swift, admob

I am having trouble integrating and initializing Admob with my simple view controller. I am receiving an error stating, "Thread 1: Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while implicitly unwrapping an Optional value". I have used Google's tutorial for how to start an AdMob app, below is my relevant code.

```
import UIKit
```

`import GoogleMobileAds`

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, GADBannerViewDelegate {
    var bannerView: GADBannerView!


override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.

    bannerView.adUnitID = "ca-app-pub-xxxxx/xxxxx" // line with error
    bannerView.rootViewController = self
    bannerView.load(GADRequest())
    // In this case, we instantiate the banner with desired ad size.
    bannerView = GADBannerView(adSize: kGADAdSizeBanner)


    bannerView.delegate = self

    func addBannerViewToView(_ bannerView: GADBannerView) {
        bannerView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        view.addSubview(bannerView)
        view.addConstraints(
            [NSLayoutConstraint(item: bannerView,
                                attribute: .bottom,
                                relatedBy: .equal,
                                toItem: bottomLayoutGuide,
                                attribute: .top,
                                multiplier: 1,
                                constant: 0),
             NSLayoutConstraint(item: bannerView,
                                attribute: .centerX,
                                relatedBy: .equal,
                                toItem: view,
                                attribute: .centerX,
                                multiplier: 1,
                                constant: 0)
        ])
    }
    addBannerViewToView(bannerView)
}


/// Tells the delegate an ad request loaded an ad.
func adViewDidReceiveAd(_ bannerView: GADBannerView) {
    print("adViewDidReceiveAd")
}

/// Tells the delegate an ad request failed.
func adView(_ bannerView: GADBannerView,
            didFailToReceiveAdWithError error: GADRequestError) {
    print("adView:didFailToReceiveAdWithError: \(error.localizedDescription)")
}

/// Tells the delegate that a full-screen view will be presented in response
/// to the user clicking on an ad.
func adViewWillPresentScreen(_ bannerView: GADBannerView) {
    print("adViewWillPresentScreen")
}

/// Tells the delegate that the full-screen view will be dismissed.
func adViewWillDismissScreen(_ bannerView: GADBannerView) {
    print("adViewWillDismissScreen")
}

/// Tells the delegate that the full-screen view has been dismissed.
func adViewDidDismissScreen(_ bannerView: GADBannerView) {
    print("adViewDidDismissScreen")
}

/// Tells the delegate that a user click will open another app (such as
/// the App Store), backgrounding the current app.
func adViewWillLeaveApplication(_ bannerView: GADBannerView) {
    print("adViewWillLeaveApplication")
}
let adSize = GADAdSizeFromCGSize(CGSize(width: 300, height: 50))
}
```

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

You must initialize the `bannerView` before accessing its properties, move up the initializer line.

```
bannerView = GADBannerView(adSize: kGADAdSizeBanner) //<---- move up to here.
bannerView.adUnitID = "ca-app-pub-xxxxx/xxxxx"
bannerView.rootViewController = self
bannerView.load(GADRequest())
```

<s>`bannerView = GADBannerView(adSize: kGADAdSizeBanner)`</s>

Comment: Thank you very much!!